# Dense Optical flow pixel indices

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, opticalflow

I have implemented the Dense optical flow algorithm in python and got the flow output as a 2D array having displacement of that pixel from the prev frame. So the flow matrix would be a matrix of the same size as the original image, and the X and Y values stored in it at certain positions would be the X and Y distance travelled to get where they currently are. So if i were to find out where they moved from I would simply use their current pixel location in the flow matrix and subtract the X and Y distances they travelled? How will I find the pixel indices(pixel positions) having absolutely no displacement?